# Compare user's input against prefabricated text chain

Tags: c#, string, linq, input

I am in my first steps towards creating a very basic structural analysis software using Visual C#.

I decided to make it console-based (no user interface). Therefore the only way to get user's input is through chars and strings.

Imagine the user wants to create a 2D bar element. She would need to specify an initial point, a final point and a name for that bar. I want the syntax to be like follows:

"CREATE bar NAMED (bar_name) FIRST (first_point) LAST (last_point)"

Where:

- (bar_name) is the name of the bar, up to the user. Let (object_name)="bar_A" (string type).
- (first_point) would be the initial point of the bar. Since we are creating a 2D bar, (first_point) should be a 1x2 vector that the user should enter between parenthesis. For example, (first_point)=(0,0)
- (last_point) would be the final point of the bar. Same type and syntax as (first_point).

I am just wondering if there is any easy way to achieve the string comparison task, something like comparing the user's input against a prefabricated command.

Of course without forgetting about user's input cleaning task.

I know there is a huge amount of possible solutions here. Maybe using LINQ. Maybe just using the String object. I just want to know the most efficient way, where efficient means:

- The fastest the user's query gets processed, the better;
- the less the lines of codes, the better; and
- where thorough query sanitizing tasks are made.

This last point is really important since some user's input like this:

"CREATE bar NAMED bar_a ***FISRT*** (0,0) LAST (0,1)"

Note that the user commited a typo (FISRT instead of FIRST), and the query shouldn't run.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)

Comment: See my project on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser

Comment: @icemanind Interesting. But you don't offer support since 2011 as I can see there, is that right?

Comment: @JosePerez - I always offer support when I can. If you want, I can put together something appropriate that should parse what you need parsed. Give me about 2 hours though because I have to step into a meeting at work in about 15 minutes.

Comment: @icemanind That sounds really great, without a doubt. May you help me with my parsing needs? I will download your project and take a deep look into it.

Comment: @JosePerez - Also, does case matter? In other words, can it be `create bar named bar_a first (0,0) last (0,1)`?

Comment: @icemanind No it doesn't, it was just for demonstration and readability purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I created a simple parser that should work good for you and, if the need arises, you can easily expand.

Start off by creating a new Console Application. Add a new class file called `Tokenizer.cs`. This file was auto generated by my TokenIcer project that I linked to you in the comments above. Make `Tokenizer.cs` look like this:

```
public class TokenParser
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Tokens, string> _tokens;
    private readonly Dictionary<Tokens, MatchCollection> _regExMatchCollection;
    private string _inputString;
    private int _index;

    public enum Tokens
    {
        UNDEFINED = 0,
        CREATE = 1,
        FIRST = 2,
        LAST = 3,
        BAR = 4,
        NAMED = 5,
        BAR_NAME = 6,
        WHITESPACE = 7,
        LPAREN = 8,
        RPAREN = 9,
        COMMA = 10,
        NUMBER = 11
    }

    public string InputString
    {
        set
        {
            _inputString = value;
            PrepareRegex();
        }
    }

    public TokenParser()
    {
        _tokens = new Dictionary<Tokens, string>();
        _regExMatchCollection = new Dictionary<Tokens, MatchCollection>();
        _index = 0;
        _inputString = string.Empty;

        _tokens.Add(Tokens.CREATE, "[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee]");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.FIRST, "[Ff][Ii][Rr][Ss][Tt]");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.LAST, "[Ll][Aa][Ss][Tt]");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.BAR, "[Bb][Aa][Rr][ \\t]");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.NAMED, "[Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee][Dd]");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.BAR_NAME, "[A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.WHITESPACE, "[ \\t]+");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.LPAREN, "\\(");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.RPAREN, "\\)");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.COMMA, "\\,");
        _tokens.Add(Tokens.NUMBER, "[0-9]+");
    }

    private void PrepareRegex()
    {
        _regExMatchCollection.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Tokens, string> pair in _tokens)
        {
            _regExMatchCollection.Add(pair.Key, Regex.Matches(_inputString, pair.Value));
        }
    }

    public void ResetParser()
    {
        _index = 0;
        _inputString = string.Empty;
        _regExMatchCollection.Clear();
    }

    public Token GetToken()
    {
        if (_index >= _inputString.Length)
            return null;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Tokens, MatchCollection> pair in _regExMatchCollection)
        {
            foreach (Match match in pair.Value)
            {
                if (match.Index == _index)
                {
                    _index += match.Length;
                    return new Token(pair.Key, match.Value);
                }

                if (match.Index > _index)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        _index++;
        return new Token(Tokens.UNDEFINED, string.Empty);
    }

    public PeekToken Peek()
    {
        return Peek(new PeekToken(_index, new Token(Tokens.UNDEFINED, string.Empty)));
    }

    public PeekToken Peek(PeekToken peekToken)
    {
        int oldIndex = _index;

        _index = peekToken.TokenIndex;

        if (_index >= _inputString.Length)
        {
            _index = oldIndex;
            return null;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Tokens, string> pair in _tokens)
        {
            var r = new Regex(pair.Value);
            Match m = r.Match(_inputString, _index);

            if (m.Success && m.Index == _index)
            {
                _index += m.Length;
                var pt = new PeekToken(_index, new Token(pair.Key, m.Value));
                _index = oldIndex;
                return pt;
            }
        }
        var pt2 = new PeekToken(_index + 1, new Token(Tokens.UNDEFINED, string.Empty));
        _index = oldIndex;
        return pt2;
    }
}

public class PeekToken
{
    public int TokenIndex { get; set; }

    public Token TokenPeek { get; set; }

    public PeekToken(int index, Token value)
    {
        TokenIndex = index;
        TokenPeek = value;
    }
}

public class Token
{
    public TokenParser.Tokens TokenName { get; set; }

    public string TokenValue { get; set; }

    public Token(TokenParser.Tokens name, string value)
    {
        TokenName = name;
        TokenValue = value;
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs`, make it look like this:

```
class Program
{
    private class Bar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int FirstX { get; set; }
        public int FirstY { get; set; }
        public int LastX { get; set; }
        public int LastY { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string commandCreateBar1 = "CREATE bar NAMED bar_a FIRST(5,10) LAST (15,20)";
        const string commandCreateBar2 = "CREATE bar NAMED MyFooBar FIRST(25  ,  31)    LAST   (153 ,210)";
        const string commandCreateBar3 = "CREATE    bar   NAMED    MySpaceyFooBar FIRST(0,0)  LAST (12,39)";

        Bar bar1 = ParseCreateBar(commandCreateBar1);
        PrintBar(bar1);

        Bar bar2 = ParseCreateBar(commandCreateBar2);
        PrintBar(bar2);

        Bar bar3 = ParseCreateBar(commandCreateBar3);
        PrintBar(bar3);
    }

    private static void PrintBar(Bar bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A new bar was Created! \"{0}\" ({1}, {2}) ({3}, {4})", bar.Name, bar.FirstX, bar.FirstY, bar.LastX, bar.LastY);
    }

    private static Bar ParseCreateBar(string commandLine)
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        var parser = new TokenParser { InputString = commandLine };

        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.CREATE);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.BAR);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.NAMED);
        Token token = Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.BAR_NAME);
        bar.Name = token.TokenValue;
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.FIRST);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.LPAREN);
        token = Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.NUMBER);
        bar.FirstX = int.Parse(token.TokenValue);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.COMMA);
        token = Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.NUMBER);
        bar.FirstY = int.Parse(token.TokenValue);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.RPAREN);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.LAST);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.LPAREN);
        token = Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.NUMBER);
        bar.LastX = int.Parse(token.TokenValue);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.COMMA);
        token = Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.NUMBER);
        bar.LastY = int.Parse(token.TokenValue);
        Expect(parser, TokenParser.Tokens.RPAREN);

        return bar;
    }

    private static Token Expect(TokenParser parser, TokenParser.Tokens expectedToken)
    {
        EatWhiteSpace(parser);
        Token token = parser.GetToken();
        if (token != null && token.TokenName != expectedToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected Token " + expectedToken);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        if (token == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected end of input!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        return token;
    }

    private static void EatWhiteSpace(TokenParser parser)
    {
        while (parser.Peek() != null && parser.Peek().TokenPeek != null && 
            parser.Peek().TokenPeek.TokenName == TokenParser.Tokens.WHITESPACE)
        {
            parser.GetToken();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I created 3 test scenarios. Notice all white space is ignored. If you want to be strict about the white space, you can modify the `EatWhiteSpace` function to be strict.

If you want, I have a simple expression parser I could throw into this code too, that way you could have commands such as `CREATE bar NAMED bar_a FIRST(3+2, 7*8 + 12) LAST (150-100, 12-3*2)`. I've got a simple expression parser I made a while back using TokenIcer that I can throw in. It can parse any math expression and supports parenthesis, add, subtract, multiply, and divide.

Comment: Hey, really beautiful code @icemanind. Giving the user the possibility to do calculations inside FIRST and LAST would be really great, how can I do it?

Now I want to move on and create other commands such as CREATE material NAMED (material_name) DENSITY (density_float_value), and so on. How can I achieve this?

Thanks again

Comment: @JosePerez -- Give me a little bit of time and I'll post new code.

Comment: I am in troubles with the ParseCreateBar method you created, I don't really know how to use and how to adapt it to my new commands (e.g. I will have DELETE, MODIFY, VIEW, CALCULATE, etc., not only CREATE, and don't know how this affects the ParseCreateBar method; furthermore I will not only have bars, but also Materials, Meshes, Distributed forces, Temperatures, etc.)

Comment: @JosePerez - Give me some time to work on this. I will adapt my parser to work with your requirements

Comment: Of course no problem, thanks for your time. Anyway I'd like to know how to use your TokenIcer as a professional but have no references

Comment: @JosePerez - Do you have an email address I can email you this to? Its getting a little long to post on here.

Comment: Sure @icemanind, you can email it to: jlgarcia92@gmail.com

Thanks for helping me mate

Answer (score 1):

Tokenization is one way to go, but if you aren't planning on supporting way too many commands and parameters, you should look at Regexes.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^CREATE bar NAMED (?<BarName>[A-Za-z0-9-_]*) FIRST (?<FirstPoint>\([0-9]+\|[0-9]+\)) LAST (?<LastPoint>\([0-9]+\|[0-9]+\)$");
Match match = regex.Match("create bar named bar_a first (0,0) last (0,1)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    var name = match.Groups["BarName"].Value;
    // and so on for other matches
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the user can create other elements, not only bars. So for example the user can create materials, point forces, distributed forces, meshes and some more objects. Each of them would require a customized set of parameters.

So for example, to create a material this syntax should be follows:

CREATE material NAME (material_name) DENSITY (density_val) [OTHER (other properties ordered in an array)]

Comment: You could first use another Regex to match the first part of the statement, then move on and evaluate other parameters

Comment: Do you think String.split() will work out in this case?